# Magento 2.3.x Membership / Recurring Billing Solution

Tags: customer, price, magento2.3, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm looking for a way to setup a membership based store using magento 2.3.x.  I need to be able to allow the customer to subscribe to a membership on a monthly or yearly billing basis (auth.net ARB) that also changes the user to a new usergroup so that I can display custom pricing etc.

I have found a membership extension (mageplaza) that changes the customer to a new group, but it doesn't natively support automatic rebilling for the membership.   Anyone have any suggestions or know if this is possible?  Payment gateway being used is Authorize.net

Comment: you have to contact extension developer on this issue